# Making a wireless clicker to use in presentations, suggestions?

Tags: wireless

I will be needing a wireless remote/clicker of some sort to use when delivering presentations for projects and assignments (i.e. Powerpoint type). Yeah, I can buy one quite cheap - but really, what fun is that?

The first thing which comes to my mind is to use a small microcontroller like the ATTiny for the receiver, connected via USB as an HID device. Then use something cheap like IR to send it the signal. I've never done this, but I think IR is the simplest and cheapest method. What other cheap alternatives should I consider? The disadvantages of IR are obvious.

In terms of functionality, it needs to have the bare minimum ability to receive a signal as an indication to move on to the next slide. I'll first tackle this first, before adding further functionality. I think if I go the HID device route, it should be pretty simple if I just program the microcontroller to send a left mouse button clicked command.

So should I use a microcontroller, or something else? What is the easiest way to do this, and what wireless technology would you recommend I use?

Thanks.

Comment: What disadvantages do you see in IR? (Just to make sure we see the things the same)

Comment: @stevenvh Sure, great question. The key disadvantage for me would be that it usually requires the transmitter to be pointing toward the receiver (but it depends on the characteristics of your environment to a certain degree I suppose). Also, the range is *usually* relatively limited. Again, I am fine with IR on the whole too, it really isn't bad. I just want to know if there are better alternatives which are not too resource intensive. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered www.socrative.com? If you don't need to connct answers with individual persons you can't beat the price... I'll be trying it tomorrow in my C++/SE course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you'll need a transmitter and a receiver :-).

***Infrared***
You mention disadvantages like limited range and having to direct the transmitter, and it will depend on the setting how bad these are. Obviously a large auditorium will be more of a problem that a 20 seat room.

Suppose we go for IR, what do we need? There's the protocol and a few codes (at least next and previous slide). For the protocol you can choose an existing one, and even use existing codes, but if you make both transmitter and receiver yourself you can also devise your own protocol. Advantage: you can make it as simple as you like, especially regarding decoding, which is more complicated than sending. One of the most simple protocols is Pulse-Pause Modulation, where you send a series of fixed-width pulses, and encode the bits in the time between pulses.

**Transmitter**
This is the easiest. Basically a microcontroller, a transistor and an IR LED. Microcontroller is asleep, and wakes up when you press a button. Start sending the modulated code until button released and go back to sleep. The finished product tomorrow morning on my desk, OK? ;-)

**Receiver**
An IR receiver is quite complex, and you don't want to make this yourself. Especially AGC is no fun. So we buy a receiver module, like from [Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/ir-receiver-modules/). This gives you the decoded signal which can be used directly by the microcontroller. Note that when the IR receiver modules don't receive a signal the AGC will lock to the noise and output that: a lot of garbage. But no worries: when a code is received this is as clean as can be, no noise whatsoever.

***RF***
The alternative is RF. You can use the same protocol and codes, and the transmitter will look almost the same. Just output the (unmodulated!) codes to an RF transmitter instead of the IR LED.

[RFM70](http://www.hoperf.com/upload/rf/RFM70.pdf) modules are small, cheap (around 5 dollar IIRC, I think Wouter knows them well) and easy to interface.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

One [Xbee 802.15.4 module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8664) as receiver = 23 USD

One Xbee 802.15.4 module as transmitter = 23 USD

Li-ion battery (400 mAh) = 8 USD

Pushbutton (connected to I/O pin on transmitter Xbee) = 0.50 USD

Satisfaction when pressing pushbutton wakes up transmitter Xbee, which then transmits the message via [I/O line passing](http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=2188) to the receiver Xbee = Priceless ;)

(A little expensive, but you could swap in a cheaper RF module as @stevenvh suggests, and also you could use a smaller battery, since your unit will be sleeping most of the time, except upon pushbutton interrupt.)